# performSegue to same ViewController from delegate method

Tags: swift, delegates

I'm trying to perform a segue from ViewController A to ViewController A (same VC). I can do that when I ctrl+drag from a button to the VC and set the identifier ("sameVC" in my case).

When the button is tapped, the segue works as expected. The problem is, I need to call

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sameVC", sender: self)
```

from a delegate. So when the button is tapped, I need to call a function, that has a delegate, like this:

```
class ViewControllerA: ViewController, MyDelegate {

  var mC = MyClass()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     mC.delegate = self
  }

  @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
     mC.myfunc()
  }

  func success {
    // Trying to call delegate
    self.performSegue(withIdentifies: "sameVC", sender: self)
  }
}

protocol MyDelegate {
  func success()
}

class MyClass {
  var delegate: MyDelegate?

  func myfunc() {
    // ...
    self.delegate.success()
  }
}
```

When the delegate comes back to ViewControllerA in "success"-function, I want to perform the segue, but the View isn't present anymore, because the segue was called implicit with "buttonTapped"-function.

When the segue isn't going to the same VC, I would just ctrl+drag from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB, but this isn't possible with only one ViewController (or I don't know how to do this).

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Comment by Hassan Eskandari works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482380/performsegue-to-same-viewcontroller-from-delegate-method#comment72106011_42482455

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ctrl+dragging from button, ctrl+drag from ViewController itself, then it will wait for you to call `performSegue`

And for going from you have more than one viewcontrollers you may want to navigate to, you can assign an Identifier to your viewControllers in your storyboard and use `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method to instantiate your desired ViewController and present it to the user, e.g. push it on top of current viewcontroller.

Comment: This is only possible, when I got two ViewControllers, you can't ctrl+drag to the same VC.

Comment: use `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to instantiate your View Controller and push it on top of current view controller